# Расстановка запятых

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые или тире? Как правильно оформить это предложение?

**На рассвете я любила гулять по морскому побережью. В это время() дремотное и тихое() пляж был пустынен**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае обособить определение следует запятыми - это основная  форма, в то время как для тире нужно обоснование. Кстати, обособленное определение здесь не имеет значение уточнения, это обычное обособление, полупредикативная связь с определяемым словом.

При обособлении тире определение приобретает характер вставки, а для этого нужны причины:   подчеркнуто добавочный характер сообщения, распространенность определения, например: "Солнце – не тусклое, не багровое, а светлое и приветливо лучезарное – встаёт над лесом".

В нашем же случае ничего этого нет.

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли!

Answer (score 3):

Можно и тире и запятые. Запятые нужны, если это уточнение, тире - если вставка.

Дополнение

Чтобы доказать свою правоту, я обратился в справочную службу  Грамма.ру. Пришел ответ.

> Использование двойного тире в данном случае возможно. Ср.: "определения, расположенные внутри предложения, могут выделяться с двух сторон знаком тире. Они приобретают значение пояснительно-уточняющих членов предложения..." (Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник. М., 2009. С. 207).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!